# Box2d and detecting mask collision in pygame

Tags: python, image, collision-detection, box2d, mask

Pygame has pygame.sprite.collide_mask to detect collision between visible part of images.

What should I do if I want to use box2d for this instead of pygame.sprite.collide_mask?